# CUDA incrementing global device counter within a kernel

Tags: cuda

I am trying to figure out solution to a simple CUDA design issue. Let's say I have a kernel, which processes data. If the data currently processed meets specified criteria, corresponding element in `outputArray` gets current counter value and the counter is being incremented.

It looks like that:

```
__global__ void setTags(INDATA* inputData, int* tags)
{
    int blockId = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x;
    int threadId = blockId * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y) + (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    if(threadId < N)
    {
        INDATA current = inputData[threadId];
        if(/* current meets some criteria */)
        {
            tags[threadId] = /*current counter value */
            /* increment counter value */
        }
    }
}
```

Number of elements which meet criteria is significantly less than all the elements. The point is that processing stays on GPU and i have my cases tagged with unique integer, ranging from 0 to number of cases that met criteria - 1. Is there a faster way to do it than doing so incrementally in single thread ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you what you want is the [`atomicAdd`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#atomicadd) function to increment some global counter which can be accessed by many threads concurrently. You could have something like this:

```
__device__ int counter; // initialise before running kernel

__global__ void setTags(INDATA* inputData, int* tags)
{
    int blockId = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x;
    int threadId = blockId * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y) + 
                   (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    if(threadId < N)
    { 
        INDATA current = inputData[threadId];
        if(/* current meets some criteria */)
        {
            int current_val = atomicAdd(&counter, 1);
            tags[threadId] = current_val;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `atomicAdd` will read the value of `counter` atomically and increment it by one in a single atomic operation. If the number of total increment operations isn't too large, this will be performant. However, because the operation serialises execution, you might look to another approach if a large number of the total threads you launch will be accessing and incrementing the global counter.

Comment: It's correct !:) I tried the same attempt, but I forgot to get current value of counter to local memory before assigment. Big mistake. Thank you !